# spark streaming for python not working in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to read from a confluent topic via spark streaming with python in databricks.

So i have 2 questions

1. I tried to read from a topic but it keeps giving me a "failed to construct kafka consumer"

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
        
        
df = spark.readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "pkc-xxxxxxxxx.confluent.cloud:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "topic1") \
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanisms", "PLAIN")\
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
  .option("kafka.sasl.username","xxxx")\
  .option("kafka.sasl.password", "xxxx")\
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")\
  .load()\
  .select('topic', 'partition', 'offset', 'timestamp', 'timestampType', 'key')
```

I then tried to do a

```py
display(df);
```

and i keep getting a
`kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer`

is there something im missing? Im trying to see my dataframe which im trying to fetch from my confluent topic

2. how do i enable spark stream to be listening to my topics continuously in databricks? On my laptop I can do a spark submit to a cluster but im not very sure in databricks.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: you need to post bigger stacktrace - you should have lines starting with `Caused by`...

Comment: I managed to fix it. all good.

Answer (score 0):

to those who are wondering why

```
df = (spark 
  .readStream 
  .format("kafka") 
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "pkc-xxxx:9092") 
  .option("subscribe", "GOOG_GLOBAL_MOBILITY_REPORT_RAW") 
  .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_SSL") 
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") 
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", """kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="xxxx" password="xxxxx";""")
  .load()
  .withColumn('key', fn.col("key").cast(StringType()))
  .withColumn('value', fn.col("value").cast(StringType()))
  )
```